# Quickest Algorithm to write for this?

Tags: algorithm, graph, ada

Given a 20x30 'sheet of graph paper' mark any even n number of cells so that every cell has an odd number of marked neighboring cells and so that all the cells connect making one 'piece'
Neighboring cells are defined as immediately adjacent cells. (All surrounding cells excluding diagonal cells).

I'm having a problem coming up with a clean algorithm. I currently have one and it's very messy and confusing and I just know there has to be a much better way to do it, I'm just not sure how. I'm looking for a quickly implemented algorithm because I don't have much time left to do the program and we have to code it in Ada which isn't a strength of mine.
I currently am making use of I made like so,
CanMark(cell); -- Checks if the cell can be marked.
HasProblem(cell); -- Checks if the cell has an even number of surrounding marked cells.
HasFix(cell); -- Checks if there is a sequence of cells that can be marked to eliminate currently existing problem.

I don't have the code with me at the moment but I will post when I get home.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Sorry for being unclear. I am just asking for a direction not for you to do my problem for me. I feel like this could be done using a graph related algorithm but don't know enough to know for sure. I don't have my code with me right at the moment, but I will certainly post it when I am able to.

Comment: Hi Shelby115, StackOverflow is here to help you with programming problems, but it's definitely not a site where you can ask users to submit a fully working solution for a problem you encountered. You'll need to provide an example of your code, and focus on a specific area where you are having problems. As stated, your question is very broad and unlikely to get the support you're looking for.

Comment: You should at least show what you have so far. Also, your problem statement makes no sense. By definition, every cell (except at edges) has 4 neighboring cells; do you mean that each cell has an odd number of _marked_ neighboring cells? Also, if working in Ada is slowing you down significantly: get a solution working in C, Java, or some other procedural language that you know and then port it to Ada.

Comment: Can you be more specific ?  Do you mean that 'every marked cell has an odd number of marked neighbours' or some other variant on the notion.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, trying to do my best to explain the problem.
I edited the original to reflect your guys' concerns.

@HighPerformanceMark
Lets say some cell on a coordinate plain of the coordinates of (1,1) is marked. Then it must have an odd number of neighbors ((1,2) (2,1) (1,0) and (0, 1)). So 1 or 3 of the surrounding cells must be marked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start small, and build up. The smallest (n=1) is simply:
*
that clearly doesn't work since there are 0 neighbors (and even number). So no solution exists for n=1. Next, try n=2. Only one choice:
**
This works. 
Now what about n=3? Doesn't work, no solution for n=3. 
Now, how can you add to it to make n=4? n=6? Can you form a pattern?

Comment: That is basically how I started, and that's currently how my current algorithm works.

Though I did just realize that I'm an idiot and did that based on n, instead of based on the graph paper dimensions so that would probably improve my algorithm.
So thank you for that.